# "Прячутся в камыши" или "в камышах"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: "прячутся в камыши" или "в камышах"?

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарю Д.Э. Розенталя «Управление в русском языке», с глаголом *прятаться* возможны два варианта управления: **куда** (*в камыши;* **направление** действия) и **где** (*в камышах;* **место** действия).